# Ruby on Rails, devise: How can i add the id of users table to posts.user_id column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

new.html.erb

```
<h3>Add post</h3>

<%= form_tag :controller=>'posts', :action=>'create' do %>
    <%= label :q, :Title %>
    <%= text_field :data, :title, :class => :addtextsize %><br/>
    <%= label :q, :Content %>
    <%= text_area  :data, :content, :rows=>10 , :class => :addtextarea %><br/>
    <%= label :q, :Category %>
    <%= select :data, :category_id, @categories_select %><br/>
    <%= label :q, :Tags %>
    <%= text_field :data, :tags, :class => :addtextsize %><br/>
    <%= label :q, :Submit %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add Post" %>
<% end %>
```

create action of PostController.rb

```
def create
    @categories_select = Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.category_name, c.id ] }
    @addpost = Post.new params[:data]
    if @addpost.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been saved successfully."
        redirect_to posts_path
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Post can not be saved, please enter information."
        render :new
        #redirect_to new_post_path
    end
end
```

Getting users.id i need to insert it into posts table. How can i do it ?

posts table

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
 user_id     | integer                | 
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: have you tried by adding a hidden field in you post with the user.id?

Comment: Is adding hidden field a good idea? Isn't using hidden field vulnurable?

Comment: Rails provide the all the security you need although I can't see the dangers of inserting a user id in a hidden field (it's not a username or anything sensible right?) in your view you can also follow the second option @Banster74 said.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to refactor your controller code a little bit by using for example collection_select in your view for categories. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise provides a helper method called `current_user` which you can use to get the authenticated user. So, you could put a hidden text input in your form, like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
```

This will allow it to be passed into your collection of `params`.

The other option would be to manually add it in the `create` method:

```
def create
    @categories_select = Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.category_name, c.id ] }
    @addpost = Post.new params[:data]
    @addpost.user_id = current_user.id
    if @addpost.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post has been saved successfully."
        redirect_to posts_path
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Post can not be saved, please enter information."
        render :new
        #redirect_to new_post_path
    end
end
```

Comment: Is adding hidden field a good idea? Isn't using hidden field vulnurable?

Comment: Yes, there is a vulnerability with hidden fields. You can use FireBug (or something similar) to change values of hidden fields, for example. In the above instance the hidden field isn't being used for authentication or anything so the risk is low. The 2nd option is safer, for sure.